# How can I append placeholder text to a pre-populated number input?

Tags: html, css, input

I have an html input that looks like this:

```
<input type="number" min="4" max="100" step="1" name="myInput" value="33">
```

I am populating the value from a cookie/storage that is getting set from a previous screen. The previous screen is asking for a party size.

From a UX perspective, it i not clear what 33 means in this screen. Since I am populating the input, I cannot use placeholder text. This is why I am wondering if there is a way to inject "People" after the value somehow.

I really like how clean the UI looks without visible form labels, so if possible, I'd like to stay away from adding them.

Here is what I have now:
[image]

This is what I am trying to accomplish (the red text):
[image]

Perhaps it is as "simple" as a background image, but I'd like to keep the spacing nice and sharp. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: There's a `placeholder` option, not sure about browser support. `<input type="number" min="4" max="100" step="1" name="myInput" value="33" placeholder = "People">`

Comment: @Bman70 which is NOT visible when the field is not empty which is OPs problem

Comment: You can add a span tag next to the input and style it appropriately with CSS.

Comment: I enjoy asking questions here like this one to be told things like that. Much appreciated for not disappointing me. If this question is a duplicate, could you please post a link to the original so other people like me could find it? That seems like it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, perhaps this will help you point you in the right direction:

HTML:

```
<label data-placeholder="people">
  <input type="number" min="4" max="100" step="1" name="myInput" value="33">
</label>
```

SCSS:

```
LABEL {
    position: relative;

    &:after {
        content: attr(data-placeholder);
        position: absolute;
        color: red;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 1em;
        right: 1em;
    }

    INPUT {
        width: 200px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-right: 5em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: If you believe that this answered your question, please mark it so :-)